# How to install Python 3.8.6 64 bit? Error 0x80070643

Tags: python, installation, python-3.8

I have an installation of Python 3.8.6 32bit, and I need the 64bit version, as I am planning on using TensorFlow. When I run the executable installer that I just downloaded from python.org, I get the following error:

[image: Installer Window]

It then proceeds to say that it had 0x80070643 and a Fatal Error during the Installation.

[image]

How do I fix this error? Preferably without needing Administrator permissions.

P.S. I am running a 64bit processor and Python 3.9 64bit installed ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it took was an install with Admin Rights. Question Solved.